Closing the div by changing the form status
In Next.js 14, I have a form
page.tsx
interface MyFormData {
  data: FormData,
  messages: string[],
  showError: boolean,
}

export default function Register() {
  const initialState: MyFormData = {
    data: new FormData(),
    messages: [],
    showError: true
  }

  const [state, formAction] = useFormState<MyFormData>(createRegisterUser, initialState)

In this form, the data is sent to the action
And if there is an error in the validation of the fields in this form, an error message is displayed.
<form action={formAction}>
 ....
{state.showError && state.messages && state.messages.length > 0 && (
    <div className="flex w-full shadow-lg rounded-lg mt-5 border border-l-transparent border-gray-200">
        <div className="bg-red-600 py-4 px-6 rounded-l-lg flex items-center">
          <MdDangerous color="white"/>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col px-4 py-6 bg-white rounded-r-lg justify-between w-full">
          {state.messages && state.messages.map((message, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="pb-2">{message}</div>
          ))} 
        </div>
        <button className="mx-4">
          <IoCloseSharp 
            onClick={() => {
              const newState = { ...state, showError: false }
              formAction(newState)
            }}
          />
        </button>
    </div>
)}
....
      <button type="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
</form>

The issue is that in the error message, there is a button to close it, and I want that when clicking the button with the IoCloseSharp icon, the state.showError is updated to false, because the action returns true if an error occurs.
However, I'm not able to do it because the formAction doesn't expect to receive arguments like newState.
Would anyone know how I could close this div?
